# How to implement GA4's new gtag approach for custom variables

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, gtag.js

I'm managing a company's internal web app that contain a database of companies, and we're tracking which of these are visited the most in terms of sector and stock exchange, and this is the old GA code. so a company has an attached sector and stock exchange value to it, and that's what we're tracking.

```
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '{{ $tracking_id }}']);
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 2,'Sector', '{{ $company_info['sector'] }}', 2]);
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 3,'Stock Exchange', '{{ $company_info['stock_exchange'] }}', 2]);
    ...
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    (function () {
        var ga = document.createElement('script');
        ga.type = 'text/javascript';
        ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
```

Now that GA4 is forced, I needed to change the code so that it gets tracked properly. The problem is that while reading the GA4, I can't see any flexible GA4 implementation that matches my use case.

As per documentation, I'd have to create custom dimensions, and from a common sense perspective, it should be item scoped dimension since im thinking the following custom dimensions should be tracked when viewing a company, which im thinking of as an item.

My goal is to produce a custom report that tallies the number of views for each company Sector recorded, and another custom report that shows the number of views per Stock Exchange.

But when creating the custom report via GA Dashboard's `Explore` tab > `Free Form`, all the item scoped custom dimensions that I made cannot be compared against `Views`.

So I created custom dimensions with `event` as the set scope. And now it can be compared against `Views` via `Explore` > `Free Form`.

Now I want to save these custom dimensions when the user visits a company page, but my new code doesn't seem to work.

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', '{{ env('GTAG_ID') }}', {
    'user_id': `{!! Auth::user()->email !!}`
    ,'event_sector': `{!! $company_info['sector'] !!}`
    ,'event_stockexchange': `{!! $company_info['stock_exchange'] !!}`
});
```

From what I understand, this is like the shortcut code where page_view is automatically tracked by google.

Any guidance or help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use **GTM (Google Tag Manager)**
Watch Videos of this Chanel [Google Tag Manager Tutorial for Beginners (2023) with New Google Tag](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DiAgCihHW58)

1- create the custom-dimensions in your analytics.google account. consider them as `event` scope.
2- open GTM ([Google Tag Manager](https://tagmanager.google.com/)): you should create an account. Then create a Tag and set the type as `Google Tag` (you can name it as you want). This tag is your analytics configuration Tag which recently is called Google Tag. Remember to set the Trigger for ALL Pages.

3- Create a custom Event Tracker Tag and set the Type to `Google Analytics:GA4 Event`. Then, you should go to the **trigger tab**, and create a trigger for your custom event (it means that when you want to initialize the trigger or the event).

[image]

Now, you need to create User-Defined Variables for all the custom dimensions
create them and define how you are going to set the values in front-end. Are they a custom java script or a dataLayer variable?
for example if it is a custom **js** function, then you can do something like the photo below:

[image]

Now go back to your event-tracker Tag and add the parameters:
[image]